# Git. Deploy subcatalogs, it is realy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku, github

I have directory: Folder/, this is repository on github.
In this directory exist another directory: Folder/Site/.
I need deploy Site/ to Heroku or VPS. I dont want creating new repository in Folder/Site and include it into Folder repo (Submodules). Any idea? This is realy? Problem in creating a submodule is that it increases the number of repositories on githab, and the repository Folder/ is private.

Comment: I need deploy like this: git@github.com:verybigman/folder.git/site

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout Git Subtree (https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). It'll let you do something like this:

```
git subtree push --prefix Site origin master
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand the difference of sub-modules. I will investigate.

Comment: From the link in my post: Subtrees are not to be confused with submodules, which are meant for
the same task. Unlike submodules, subtrees do not need any special
constructions (like .gitmodule files or gitlinks) be present in
your repository, and do not force end-users of your
repository to do anything special or to understand how subtrees
work. A subtree is just a subdirectory that can be
committed to, branched, and merged along with your project in
any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to fork the buildpack you are currently using (I'm assuming you use the Cedar stack here) and modify it to work on a subdir of the git tree instead of its root. See the [Buildpack documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) on Heroku's Dev Center.